# Gtk 3.0 MenuItem() with Grid()

Tags: python, gtk3, ubuntu-18.04

I'm trying to create a Menu with Gtk3 and Python which has its entries aligned like a HTML-table. the values of the columns are of different length. i want the menu look like this:

```
entry 1      text-of-some-length     1000
entry 2      shorter-text            10
entry 2      shorter-text            100
```

I thougth i can simply use a Gtk.Grid() add Gtk.Labels() to it and then append the grid to the Gtk.MenuItem(). Here is my attempt

```
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk, GObject
gi.require_version('AppIndicator3', '0.1')
from gi.repository import AppIndicator3 as appindicator
from os.path import expanduser

#init AppIndicator3 in class
self.ind = appindicator.Indicator.new ("todo-txt-indicator", PANEL_ICON, appindicator.IndicatorCategory.OTHER)
self.ind.set_status (appindicator.IndicatorStatus.ACTIVE)

#generate menu for AppIndicator3
menu = Gtk.Menu()

label_1 = Gtk.Label ()
label_1.set_text ('entry 1')

label_2 = Gtk.Label ()
label_2.set_text ('text-of-some-length')

label_3 = Gtk.Label ()
label_3.set_text ('1000')

grid = Gtk.Grid ()
grid.add (label_1)
grid.attach_next_to (label_2, label_1, Gtk.PositionType.RIGHT, 1, 1)
grid.attach_next_to (label_3, label_2, Gtk.PositionType.RIGHT, 1, 1)

menu_item = Gtk.MenuItem ()
menu_item.add (grid)

menu.append (menu_item)

#set menu to AppIndicator3
self.ind.set_menu (menu)
```

But this don't work. only the last element (label_3) gets displayed (at the most left position). I don't see why this isn't working. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you post mcve? There is nothing wrong with Grid itself, but maybe something is wrong with menu.

Comment: By the way, it's not clear, why you want to pack a grid to menu. Maybe `TreeView` fits more?

Comment: @AlexanderDmitriev that is pretty much my mcve. I just want the menu-enties to have dynamic space between the 3 values. So a TreeView is to much. it should be simple.

Comment: When I've wrapped this code a little with GtkWindow and GtkMenuBar instead of menu it worked ok, thus I can't reproduce what you have. That's why I ask you for mCve

Comment: @AlexanderDmitriev ah ok i understand you. i thought you meant some changes to the Menu() object. I updated my question. The whole thing is an AppIndicator3 app